# chart js showing some weird data at top of charts

Tags: chart.js

Some weird data is appearing at top left corner of the chart js graph tried removing code js and html to debug the problem but was unable to understand. if someone could help into this issue.

[some weird data at top left corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXo6d.png)

Answer (score 0):

Was having Extra axis configured for chart JS but was not setting data for that axis so NAN was displayed at the top for that axes in cart JS